# Vim emulation in IDEs vs gVim as IDE

Tags: vim, gvim, ide

I am currently using gVim as editor and cannot think about going back to mode-less editing. I code in Java for Android and in Python for another project.

While trying to set up gVim as my primary Python IDE, I have jumped through hoops looking for and installing plugins but its still not as good as when I use IntelliJ with vim emulation for Android.

So my question is, is it worth installing and familiarizing myself with tons of plugins (NERDTree, Command-T, RopeVim; and I believe setting vim up for Android will be asking for even more trouble) or should I just install PyCharm and enable vim emulation? Can gVim ever provide me with useful debugging? (Watch windows, conditional breakpoints, logcat integration etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim can get close(r) to an IDE in terms of features via various plugins, but it will always remain a powerful text editor with great extension capabilities. So for anything larger than a hobby project, you'll certainly miss IDE features like debugging, variable inspection, refactoring, find usages, etc.

But why not have both? It's easy to set up a command to load the current file (at the current position) in GVIM (with `--remote` reusing a running instance), and both Vim and IDEs typically handle external file changes quite well. With that, you have the best of both worlds, just at the cost of switching between them (with Alt-Tab), and a little duplicated file / buffer management.

I personally use IntelliJ IDEA (with default keybindings, so that I can still use it at a colleague's system) and GVIM together. Major editing is done in Vim, browsing, refactoring and debugging in the IDE.